# Remove resource requirements of SGE jobs using qalter

Tags: queue, cluster-computing

So I have pending jobs on an SGE queue. The job is running with the parameters

`-l h_rt=1200,h_vmem=16g`

I know that I can use `qalter` to change the parameters.

`qalter -l h_rt=1300 jid`

But how do I remove these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a method to reset these values to their default value.
However, you can manually check what the defaults are and then apply those.

This will show the default values for queue `all.q`:

```
qconf -sq all.q
```

If you did not apply complex modifications to your SGE setup, the hard resource limits will likely be `INFINITY`. So you can reset the limits via

```
qalter -l h_rt=INFINITY jid
```

Keep in mind that above command will also replace your other limits (e.g. `h_vmem`). If you wish to keep these other settings you will have to re-assign them in your `qalter` command.